# Consumir un APi desde VBA excel

Tags: json, excel, api, vba

Hola sucede que estoy consumiendo una API de la cual me dan el URL a la cual le debo agregar unos parámetros para que me arroje un resultado.

Esta API me retorna un JSON el cual debo cargar en a una tabla en Excel

Me base en esta [pag](https://codingislove.com/excel-json/)

Este es mi codigo que finalmente funciona pero lo extraño es que no me trae los datos de position y orientation

```html
Option Explicit

Sub TestTablas()
    Dim Tablas As QueryTable
    Dim url As String
    Dim id As Integer
    Dim startDate As String
    Dim endDate As String

    Dim req As Object
    Dim strjson As String
    Dim jp As Object
    Dim dict
    Dim subdict
    Dim subsubdict
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim roleJson As String
    Dim jpRoles As Object
    Dim items
    Dim itemsId
    Dim attr
    Dim itemattr
    
    id = Hoja10.Range("C2")
    startDate = Format(Hoja10.Range("C3"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    endDate = Format(Hoja10.Range("C4"), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")
    url = "https://xxx.yyy.com/api/zzz?id=" & id& "&startDate=" & startDate & "&endDate=" & endDate & "&timezone=-6"
        
    Set req = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    req.Open "GET", url, False
    req.Send
    
    Set jp = JsonConverter.ParseJson(req.ResponseText)
    Set items = jp("items")
    
    roleJson = req.ResponseText
    Set jpRoles = JsonConverter.ParseJson(roleJson)
    Set items = jpRoles("items")
    
    i = 7
    For Each itemsId In items
        For Each attr In itemsId
           ' Debug.Print attr
            'Debug.Print itemsId(attr)
            
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 1).Value = itemsId("name")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 2).Value = itemsId("Position")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 3).Value = itemsId("positionDate")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 4).Value = itemsId("latitude")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 5).Value = itemsId("longitude")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 6).Value = itemsId("Orientation")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 7).Value = itemsId("speed")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 8).Value = itemsId("receiptDate")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 9).Value = itemsId("notification")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 10).Value = itemsId("kilometers")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 11).Value = itemsId("unitVoltage")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 12).Value = itemsId("gpsVoltage")
            Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 13).Value = itemsId("satellites")
            
        Next attr
         i = i + 1
    Next itemsId
    
End Sub
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ejemplo del JSON

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dale algun alert o trata de imprimir en alguna celda el valor de esa variable `JSON`

Comment: @fredyfx En el ejemplo que me base Item no lo declaran, al menos no entiendo donde, si yo lo declaro como Dim Item As Object, me dice que se requiere un objeto y me marca error, si lo declaro como tipo variant me imprime la palabra  "success" asi Hoja10.Range("A1") = Item, pero me marca un error diciendo que no coinciden los tipos aqui: Sheets(7).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("name")

Comment: Si quiero ver que tiene JSON me marca un error "error definido por la aplicacion o por el objeto" aqui Hoja10.Range("A1") = JSON @fredyfx

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que consigues en `http.ResponseText` por favor?. Solía programar en VBA hace buen tiempo para Macros en Excel, me ha dado nostalgia :D

Comment: osea quieres ver  el JSON que obtengo de la api? @fredyfx

Comment: la respuesta que viene en `http.ResponseText` que en teoría sí es el JSON, quiero comprobar :D Por otro lado, me gustaría ver esa función de Parse que usas

Comment: Listo, ya actualice la pregunta @fredyfx

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105489/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-huntzberger).

Comment: Creo que tu código está OK, peeeeero, estás escribiendo mal las claves para los casos en que no te funciona. Si observas, las tienes escrita con la 1ª letra en mayúscula. Si lo pones así debería funcionar: **`Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 2).Value = itemsId("position")`**  y  **`Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 6).Value = itemsId("orientation")`**. Me parece que los nombres de clave en JSON son *case sensitive*.

Comment: rayos tiene usted razon @A.Cedano ya funciono muchas gracias jajaja :c

Comment: Moraleja: empezar a depurar por lo más simple... y luego ir pasando a lo más complejo. Me alegro de que con eso haya funcionado. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las propiedades de los objetos JSON suelen ser *case sensitive*, lo cual significa que `Position` y `position` o `Orientation` y `orientation` no son lo mismo.

En la imagen se ve claramente que esas propiedades en el JSON están en minúscula, pero tú las estas buscando como propiedades en mayúscula.

Si lo pones así, debería funcionar:

```
        Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 2).Value = itemsId("position")
        ...
        Sheets("Informacion").Cells(i, 6).Value = itemsId("orientation")
```